# I can’t understand why the premium of two butterflies with same strike but different broadness are approximately the same

Tags: option-pricing, finance, quant-trading-strategies, finance-mathematics, option-strategies

Consider the following premiums of calls option with different strikes.
C90 = 57.35
C95 = 52.55
C100 = 47.3
C105 = 42.9
C110 = 38.25
In this case, the butterfly 90-100-110 cost 1 and the 95-100-105 cost 0.85.
I expected them to be very different. By drawing the payoff curve, I expected the payoff to be at least 4 times higher..
Thanks !

Comment: You do not say how you got these prices. These problems are often caused by using prices of transactions that did not occur at the same time (non-simultaneity problem). It would be better to use the bid-ask midpoint of the different options rather than possibly stale transaction prices.

Comment: Yes of course, my bad. These prices are yesterday prices for Apple on Bloomberg. Prices for C90 C95 C105 and C110 are ask price and C100 is bid price

Comment: What is the payoff of the butterfly if the price of Apple at expiry is the current market price?

Comment: You mean if the current market price is the middle of the butterfly right ? Then it’s the difference between the two closest calls. It’s 5 in my example

Comment: No, I meant your butterflies. Do you mind showing your calculations? At least 4 times is generally not possible. If one costs 1, the other 0.85, you have this guaranteed loss outside of your range.

Comment: 4 times 0 is still 0 right. When my little butterfly is not 0 then the other one pays more than twice (it pays the small butterfly payoff plus 5). You can add to this that the big butterfly pays between 90-95 and 105-110 while the little one don’t

Comment: And how is it at least 4x higher in this case? The probability of the underlying ending up in that range itself is already very small. So you have a very high chance of not earning anything.

Comment: I agree on that but here is another way of seeing my issue. I can really easily find an arbitrage by longing the big butterfly and shorting two small ones. By doing that, the payoff of my option is positive and the price I’m paying is negative

Comment: so if you can sell the tighter butterfly for more than 0.5 seems there is an arb. But assuming you are going to short the tight butterflies, you should take the bid prices of c95, c105 and ask of c100

Comment: Yes of course but even with that I’m making money. I think these butterflies are not arbitrated because of the trading fees. But also, if the butterflies are that much misspriced, some of the call should also be misspriced. It’s odd on such a liquid equity.

Comment: My first idea was to look at butterflies to assess the option-implied probability of the price at maturity. Do we agree that I can do so by saying that the probability of the price to be at 100 (99.5-100.5) is the price of the butterfly cantered on 100 divided by the square of the call’s strikes difference ? I think that’s right. Right ?

Answer (score 2):

The following argument shows that the price of the big fly should be approximately 4* the price of the small fly:   Consider the portfolio of large flies B(0,10,20)+B(10,20,30)+……B(80,90,100)+….+all the way to infinity. This portfolio pays exactly 10 at maturity.  Hence each fly represents 1/10 of the probability of being in the range of the fly, in a sense.  This approximation works if we approximate each fly by a digital payoff , for example B(90,100,110) represents 1/10 the probability that the stock finishes in the range (95,105).  A similar argument for the small flies shows that B(95,100,105) represents 1/20 of the probability of being in the range (97.5,102.5).  Then it’s easy to see that these should be in the approximate ratio 4:1.  This was intuitively obvious by looking at the payoff diagrams.  As others point out , any large deviation from this in the marketplace is almost certainly due to asynchronous data or transaction costs.

Answer (score 1):

In most realistic scenarios, the price of Apple will end up outside the range of your proposed butterflies and you simply pay or receive the costs. Insofar, your argument with going long the 90-100-110 and shorting the 95-100-110 twice sounds plausible given your numbers. However, bear in mind what @nbbo2 wrote in the first comment:

> These problems are often caused by using prices of transactions that
> did not occur at the same time (non-simultaneity problem).

If you look up the option prices on Bloomberg (`OMON`), you see the following picture on October 6th.

[image]

As you can see, the volume column (Volm) is either not showing any volume, or very low volumes for almost all strikes you consider (you did not specify the expiry date but it should be similar for all expiries). If you now look at `GIT`, you can see when these prices were observed.

[image]

There is a considerable mismatch in terms of timing, which means you are not using prices that reflect the actual costs of your butterflies if you were to buy them simultaneously.

If you price it with `OVME`, you can use the OTC mode to use a VOL surface (called `BVOL` here), that you could also look up on `OVDV`. Doing this gives the following butterfly prices.
[image]
[image]

```
56.8076371  | 52.0521078
-94.6852675 | -94.6852675
38.1983043  | 42.7308402
------------------------
=0.3206740  | =0.0976805
```

In this case, your argument no longer holds.

Regarding your last comment, you do not have 99.5 and 100.5 but 95 and 105. In any case, the prices you looked at were almost certainly not from the same time period. How to (best) assess risk neutral probabilities using option prices is a separate question really.